# Windows keeps randomly detecting a disabled monitor

Tags: windows, display, multiple-monitors, displayport

I have two displays connected, a primary (TV) through HDMI 2.1, and a secondary (monitor) through displayport. I only occasionally use the monitor so I leave it disabled, through winkey+P > *"Second screen only"*.

Randomly, I'll hear a device disconnected sound followed by a device connected sound, the TV screen will stutter, and then the monitor will briefly show the "no input detected" message. After enabling PnP event audit logs, I can see several *"A new external device was recognized by the system."* events:

[event viewer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIQZi.png)

Any idea of what could be causing it, or how I could disable these hardware detecting events?

The only clue I have is about the times it tends to happen, mostly (but not only) past 8pm. I thought it had to do with Windows detecting a local network device and triggering it, but I disabled network sharing & discovery and it made no difference.

Other things:

- I'm using Windows 11, but it'd also happen with 10 as well;
- Replacing the displayport cable didn't help;
- No changes after upgrading my video card;
- There are no issues altogether if I just keep the monitor enabled. No signal drops, reconnections nor random stutters.

Answer (score 0):

1. The *FIRST* thing to do is to update your drivers (if you haven't already).
2. Carefully check all cables (video cable, power cord, etc).  Make sure all the connections are solid.

   - It sounds like you've already done this...
3. Switch monitors:

   - See if the problem moves with the display device, or stays with the video card
4. Post back what you find!

Comment: 1) I did a fresh Win11 install so drivers should be up to date, also tried to install the monitor manufacturer's driver. 2) Yep, done that, since I replaced the cable once. 3) I don't have another displayport monitor, but I ruled out an issue with the port/monitor since there are no issues as long as it remains enabled.

Comment: 1) Re drivers: *NEVER ASSUME*.  Sometimes the drivers don't change for YEARS ... sometimes they can change every 15 minutes.  I'm sure your drivers are the former ... but it only takes a few moments to LOOK...  3) It's essential that we try to isolate the problem to a) cabling/connectors, b) your PC video card(s)/chip(s), c) the physical display device.  Q: Do you have *ONE* "video card" (e.g. integrated graphics)?  Q: Do you have *TWO* display ports (e.g. an HDMI and a VGA or DVI port)?  Q: Can you think of *ANY* way to isolate to TV or monitor?